# Given a string that when appended to my domain would give me the appropriate url, how do you generate a link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Given the following string:

```
/MyController/MyAction/4
```

How do I generate a link within another controller's action to link to the appropriate address?

If I do the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("click", Url.Action(item.Link)) 
// where item.Link is where /MyController/MyAction/4 is stored
```

I get a link that resembles:

```
www.localhost.com/CurrentController/CurrentController/MyController/MyAction/4
```

I need to not have the "CurrentController" part (yes, there are two of them - I think that is because I am doing a @Html.ActionLink and an Url.Action).

How would I get my appropriate link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the `/MyController/MyAction/4` path you need stored in `item.Link`, could you just build the `<a>` tag yourself?

```
<a href="@item.Link">Link Text</a>
```

Comment: How on earth does it not feel very 'MVC'? You should not feel that by virtue of using MVC, you're obligated to use helper methods for everything. If you want some html, just write the html.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [RouteUrl() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl.aspx) to achieve what you want. For more information, you can check [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#creating_urls_from_routes) as well.

Comment: This seems like the appropriate answer, but Scrooby's solution (although painfully obvious) appears to be elegant enough to overrule this one for my specific needs.  Thank you for showing me this though, I will now be aware of this in the future when needed.

Comment: All right. I personally always try to use this method rather than yours, especially if you are using partial views that can be reused, your current method might give you problems :). Anyway, I am glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are wanting is to link to another controller and action?

You need to do this;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click", "ActionName", new {Controller = "ControllerName"})
```

Then you can add some HtmlAttributes onto that to;

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Click", "ActionName", new {Controller = "ControllerName"}, new { @class= "className" })
```

**Edit**

If you are passing this string value in, then why not just use;

```
<a href="@item.Link">Click</a>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that far.  But I do not know how to cleanly get my string "/MyController/MyAction/4" into that ActionLink.